# How do I solve this problem using extended Euclidean Algorithm? 19d $\equiv$ 1 (mod 96)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I understand through trial and error that d=91, but trial and error is extremely inefficient and slow. I understand that you can use the extended Euclidean Algorithm to find d faster, but I'm encountering some unexpected problem. For some reason, I'm unable to move past the first step, could someone point out what I'm missing.

19d $\equiv$ 1 (mod 96)

96 = 5*19 + 1

$1 = 96 - 5\times19 = 3\times2^5 - 5\times19$

Comment: $5 \times 19 \equiv (-1) \pmod{96} \implies (-5) \times 19 \equiv 1 \pmod{96}$.  Then $(91) \equiv (-5) \pmod{96}.$

Comment: How did you get -1?

Comment: By your own analysis, $(5 \times 19) + 1 = 96 \implies (5 \times 19) = (96 - 1).$  This implies that $(5 \times 19) \equiv (96 - 1) \equiv (-1) \pmod{96}.$

Comment: Also, $(5 \times 19) = (96 - 1) \implies ([-5] \times 19) = (1 - 96).$  This implies that $([-5] \times 19) \equiv (1 - 96) \equiv (1) \pmod{96}.$